# How to place a JasperReport chart on JFrame?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there a way to display a JasperChart on JFrame instead of JasperViewer?

I am thinking to make a chart similar to green resource chart on Windows Task Manager interface.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that JFreeChart meets my need. Look at here : http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/